# How to get exact position canvas in chrome for android?

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, canvas

I use a tag canvas 1:1 with screen . i tried get position x,y when click 1 point in canvas:

```
var bRect = theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left)*(theCanvas.width/bRect.width);
var mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top)*(theCanvas.height/bRect.height);
```

It work fine in Chrome, IE , safari in iOS but it is so wrong so much in chrome for Android. How to fix it across all browser?

Comment: This issue happen when i open key board.